# Haskell, graph, put function into most general form -> Eq

Tags: haskell

I would like to put the 2 functions (`color` and `check`) into the most general form
`Eq a => ...`.
But I don't know how to do that.

This is a very simple graph: each node has 2 neighbours, and any adjacent nodes must have different colors

```
color ::  [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)] -> Bool
color x [] = True
color a ((x,y):rest) =
    if check a x == check a y
    then False
    else color a rest

check :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int
check [] x = 999
check ((x,y):rest) p =
    if x == p
    then y
    else check rest p
```

At the end, `colors` gives you `True` or `False`

```
Main> colors [('a',"purple"),('b',"green"),('c',"blue")] [('a','b'),('b','c'),('c','a')]
True

Main> colors [('a',"purple"),('b',"green"),('c',"purple")] [('a','b'),('b','c'),('c','a')]
False

Main> colors [('1',"purple"),('2',"green"),('3',"blue")] [('1','2'),('2','3'),('3','1')]
True

Main> colors [('1',"4"),('2',"5"),('3',"6")] [('1','2'),('2','3'),('3','1')]
True

Main> colors [('1',"4"),('2',"4"),('3',"5")] [('1','2'),('2','3'),('3','1')]
False
```

Any help is welcome  (+ if you can fix x = 999 into False).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For starters, the reason you can't generalize the `Int` to an `Eq a` is because of the 999 hard-coded in `check`.  If you just leave some random value in there, you *must* know its type, so you cannot generalize the function beyond that (well, in this particular case, you can generalize to `Eq a, Num a`, but not more).

So, the answer is to not use some arbitrary value, but instead wrap the return of `check` into a type that has a "failure" case, namely `Maybe`.

Renaming the variables to follow Haskell conventions, and giving the functions a bit more elucidating names, we get:

```
canColor ::  Eq a => [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)] -> Bool
canColor _ [] = True
canColor xs ((x,y):rest) =
    if findNeighbour xs x == findNeighbour xs y
    then False
    else canColor xs rest

findNeighbour :: Eq a => [(a, a)] -> a -> Maybe a
findNeighbour [] _ = Nothing
findNeighbour ((x,y):rest) z =
    if x == z
    then Just y
    else findNeighbour rest z
```

The idea here is that `findNeighbour` returns `Nothing` if it can't find anything, or `Just 23` if it finds 23 (or whatever it finds).

As it happens, `findNeighbour` is already defined: it's called `lookup`.  So, you could rewrite your code as:

```
canColor ::  Eq a => [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)] -> Bool
canColor _ [] = True
canColor xs ((x,y):rest) =
    if lookup x xs == lookup y xs
    then False
    else canColor xs rest
```

Now, we note that you are basically checking a predicate against all items in a list.  There's a function for this: `all`.  So, we can shorten the code to:

```
canColor ::  Eq a => [(a, a)] -> Bool
canColor xs = all (\(x, y) -> lookup x xs /= lookup y xs) xs
```

Comment: Phew, what luck. I was just about starting to type it up, now I don't have to, +1.

Comment: +1 nice answer, but I have a nitpick: the `999` isn't an `Int`, rather it is `Num a => a`, so one could generalise to `Eq a, Num a => ...` just by removing the type signatures of the original versions.

Comment: @scvalex : 
Hey, one more quastion,
question, Is it also possible to declare that,

eg. [( char, Int) , ( char, Int) , (  char, Int) ]  [(char,char),(char,char),(char,char)]
So that the second argument of the first tuplet has a different type than the first argument

Comment: @DieterVerbeemen No, because your algorithm compares the two elements of the tuple (so, they need to have the same type).  The problematic bit of code is `lookup x xs == lookup y xs`; from that, we see that `x` and `y` have the same type.